# How to add/remove audio endpoints in a custom audio endpoint enumerator dynamically?

Tags: c++, windows, audio, rds

In short, I have two questions:

1. how to add/remove audio endpoints in a "custom audio endpoint enumerator" dynamically?
2. how to notify other DLLs/Apps after the devices are created/removed?

In long words:

Is there any example or code snippet to show how to add/remove audio endpoints in a "custom audio endpoint enumerator" dynamically? In a remote RDS session, can we create/remove audio endpoints during session connection? Looks the "mstsc.exe" have this ability but we don't know how it does.

I've checked the guide for "custom audio endpoint enumerator" and other documents from Google/MSDN, such as [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/TermServ/implementing-an-audio-endpoint-enumerator).

I found I couldn't get any clue to add/remove audio endpoints dynamically.
As the custom audio endpoint enumerator is a DLL, I think it should be OK to create a dedicated thread in the DLL and wait for a signal to create audio endpoints(not sure whether is a good practice for the enumerator but let's put it aside first). Then here comes the 2nd question: how to let the system or other applications/dlls be aware of this because they might have started(such as the audiodg.exe which runs as a service)? My understanding is the function "GetTSAudioEndpointEnumeratorForSession" needs to be called if any audio endpoint is created or removed thus others could know it. But how to re-trigger this function call for other processes(or is it necessary to do this)?

Great thanks in advance for any suggestion!
(I posted the same question in MSDN form hoping to get a luck [here and there](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsdesktop/en-US/1a7167b8-7b42-4e23-9547-d2a1dbbe96c3/how-to-addremove-audio-endpoints-in-a-custom-audio-endpoint-enumerator-dynamically?forum=windowspro-audiodevelopment).)

Comment: We've gotten some info and progress from MSDN: "OK, then as far as I can tell you're doing everything right, and either you're running into a lack-of-feature, or there's a bug in Windows, or there's a bug in your custom IMMDeviceEnumerator implementation." Please refer to [the discussion thread from MSDN](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsdesktop/en-US/1a7167b8-7b42-4e23-9547-d2a1dbbe96c3/how-to-addremove-audio-endpoints-in-a-custom-audio-endpoint-enumerator-dynamically?forum=windowspro-audiodevelopment).